# Rでパッケージのインストールでエラーが表示されてしまう

Tags: r

Rx64 4.1.2でSteel-Dwass検定をする際、
「パッケージ」→「パッケージのインストール」→「Japan(Tokyo)」→「NSM3」
の指示通りにするが、Japanを選択以降、以下のメッセージが表示されてしまい、NSM3を選択出来ません。

```
 utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
 --- このセッションで使うために、CRAN のミラーサイトを選んでください --- 
 警告:  unable to access index for repository https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib:
   URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib/PACKAGES' を開けません 
 install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) でエラー: 
   引数 "pkgs" がありませんし、省略時既定値もありません
```

ファイアウォールの設定を見直したりしましたが、設定がうまく出来ていないのか進みません。

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

```
> utils:::menuInstallPkgs()
 --- このセッションで使うために、CRAN のミラーサイトを選んでください --- 
 警告:  unable to access index for repository https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib:
   URL 'https://cran.ism.ac.jp/src/contrib/PACKAGES' を開けません 
 install.packages(lib = .libPaths()[1L], dependencies = NA, type = type) でエラー: 
   引数 "pkgs" がありませんし、省略時既定値もありません 
>
```

##### スクリプト

```
# 以下のサイトを参考に作成した
# https://jojoshin.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/05/29/222528
# https://biolab.sakura.ne.jp/steel-dwass.html
# 事前にNSM3パッケージをインストールすること
# 「パッケージ」→「パッケージのインストール」→「Japan(Tokyo)」→「NSM3」
# 一回だけやれば、次からはやる必要ありません

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
library(NSM3)
# データの読み込み
# データを入力したファイル名に応じて、下の行の「Kruskal-Wallis_data.csv」の部分を書き換えること
data <- read.csv("Kruskal-Wallis_data.csv", header=T)
data
summary(data)

# Steel-Dwassの方法による多重比較
# 3群以上を多重比較するノンパラメトリック検定です
# 結果が表示されるまでに数分程度かかる場合があります
# データを入力したファイルの1行目の内容を変えた場合、それに応じて下の行の「Y」と「X」を書き換えること
# もしエラーが出るようなら、下の行の「method="Monte Carlo"」を「method="Asymptotic"」にする
XX <- as.factor(data$X)
pSDCFlig(data$Y, XX, method="Asymptotic")
```

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[【メモ】RStudioでパッケージがインストールできない人向けのメモ](https://qiita.com/Maki-Daisuke/items/0378626c9bf9971f3822), [64bit Windowsでのパッケージのインストール](http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?64bit%20Windows%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB)

Answer (score 0):

CRAN のミラーサイトを「0-Cloud」で試してみてはいかがでしょうか？
（試しにやってみましたがインストールできました）